# Strange result from DecryptByPassphrase

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying encrypt and decrypt one column in table. My code is like this:

```
drop table EncryptString
go
create table EncryptString(db int, String varchar(100))
go
insert into EncryptString values (2, '123456789')
go
ALTER TABLE EncryptString
ADD StringEncrypted varbinary(256); 
GO

declare @Pass nvarchar(512)
set @Pass = 'somepassword'
update EncryptString set StringEncrypted = ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@Pass, String, 1,                 convert( varbinary(128), db))
where db = 2

select * From EncryptString

SELECT db, StringEncrypted 
AS 'Encrypted String', CONVERT(nvarchar,
DecryptByPassphrase('somepassword', StringEncrypted, 1 
, CONVERT(varbinary, db)))
AS 'Decrypted String' FROM EncryptString
WHERE db = 2;
```

Why my 'Decrypted String' is like this:
㈱㐳㘵㠷9

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are encrypting a `varchar` but then converting to `nvarchar` from the binary `varchar` representation when decrypting.

i.e. effectively you are doing `SELECT CAST(CAST('123456789' AS VARBINARY(30)) AS NVARCHAR(30))`

If you alter the decryption bit to `CONVERT(varchar` it works as expected. You can then cast from `varchar` to `nvarchar` if required.

Comment: I had the same problem after following the Microsoft documentation at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188910.aspx Thanks for the fix and explanation.